# How to achieve nodding detection in Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have started coding for Google Glass. I am developing a sample application which will detect whether a user is nodding or not. More preciously, I want to detect whether it is nod "Yes" or nod "NO" so that I can perform some action.

What's the best way of detecting it since ORIENTATION_SENSOR is deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Level](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-level-sample) or [Compass](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample) samples that make use of the sensors.

The Level sample uses the `GRAVITY_SENSOR` to compute the head orientation on the desired axis. The logic resides in the [`LevelRenderer`](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-level-sample/blob/master/src/com/google/android/glass/sample/level/LevelRenderer.java) class:

```
    /**
     * Compute the orientation angle.
     *
     * @param event Gravity values.
     */
    private void computeOrientation(SensorEvent event) {
        float angle = (float) -Math.atan(event.values[0]
                / Math.sqrt(event.values[1] * event.values[1] + event.values[2] * event.values[2]));

        mLevelView.setAngle(angle);
    }
```

Simply change the vectors used in the angle computation to change axis.

Comment: ohh thanks alot I'll look into it , and will tell you whether it is working or not ! :D